# Show previously loaded tiles while loading (zoom in or zoom out) map

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript, geowebcache, ext-js

How to remove the white tile part(map loading area).

[image]

While zoom in and zoom out, the white tile part is appearing on the map(map loading area). How can we fill that area with the history image?

Is there any better way to load maps faster than the GeoWebCache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using openlayers library to load your mapping tiles. In openlayers there are two transitions that are currently implemented Default & Resize. Default is used when no transition is specified while resize effect resamples the current tile and displays it stretched or compressed until the new tile is available.

Sample Code:

```
var resize_tiles_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "TITLE", 
                "TILE_URL",
                {layers: 'LAYER_NAME'}, 
                {singleTile: true, transitionEffect: 'resize'}
            );
```

or check out http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/transition.html

Comment: Dear Farhat Abbas..Thank you for your support it was really helpful..:)

Comment: Dear Sandhya and Aragon...Thank you for your support..(y) :)